# How to loop through an object by using the .forEach() method and store the result in a new array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, foreach

I want to loop throught the object, dogNames, and return only the names of dogs I own into the array, myDogs. I want myDogs to appear as such when logged:

['Remington','Ruby','Chief','Link']

Most likely, I'm not understanding how the .forEach() method works and/or how to manipulate objects. This is some homework help an I'm just not understanding the .forEach() method after a few hours on this. Thank you for any help. Please just point me in the right direction, I don't want other people to solve this.

First, here is the array I've written.

```
var dogNames = [
  {name: Kevin,     mine: false},
  {name: Remington, mine: true},
  {name: Bingo,     mine: false},
  {name: Ruger,     mine: false},
  {name: Ruby,      mine: true},
  {name: Gino,      mine: false},
  {name: Chief,     mine: true},
  {name: Watson,    mine: false},
  {name: Link,      mine: true}
];
```

This is the array I want to store the result to.

```
var myDogs = [];
```

This is what I've attempted to do after some google.

```
dogNames.forEach(function(mine){
    if(mine === true){
        myDogs.push(dogNames.name);
    }
});
```

Comment: You're looking for `.filter()` & `.map()`

Comment: I wish I was. I need to use .forEach()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you iterate through `dogNames` the argument in `function` is each object.  So what you think is `mine` is actually the entire object.

Instead:

```
dogNames.forEach(dogName => {
    if(dogName.mine === true){
        myDogs.push(dogName.name);
    }
});
```

Comment: `dogName.mine` is a boolean, you don't need to compare to `true`

Comment: This was exactly what I wasn't understanding, thank you.

Comment: No problem, and Ele is correct, you can just use `if(dogName.mine)`

Comment: I'm going to a code boot camp in just a few day and don't understand how things work too well. Could you explain, or maybe just give a link about, how boolean values can be used?

Comment: At least in the context of your current question: for an `if` statement, if the code between the parenthesis evaluates to `true` it will execute the code between the brackets.  The values for `mine` are all either `true` or `false` and do not need to be further evaluated.  What you're saying right now is `if(true === true)` when really you just need `if(true)`

Comment: I've expounded on this a bit in my answer below.  Good luck at your Code Camp @CodyDillman

Answer (score 2):

You could filter and the array and map the names of the filtered array.

```js
var dogNames = [{ name: 'Kevin', mine: false }, { name: 'Remington', mine: true }, { name: 'Bingo', mine: false }, { name: 'Ruger', mine: false }, { name: 'Ruby', mine: true }, { name: 'Gino', mine: false }, { name: 'Chief', mine: true }, { name: 'Watson', mine: false }, { name: 'Link', mine: true }],
    myDogs = dogNames
        .filter(({ mine }) => mine)
        .map(({ name }) => name)
     
console.log(myDogs);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your approach:

```
dogNames.forEach(function(mine){
    if(mine === true){
        myDogs.push(dogNames.name);
    }
});
```

mine is basically a single element of the array so to access the property of that element you will need dot notation. You can use `mine.mine` to access the mine property and `mine.name` to access the name. Now just do the correct comparison and push the correct value in the array.

Though, you dont need to use .forEach(), easier approach is to use `.filter()` and `.map()`  to return the value of `name` key from the array for mine true.

```
dogNames.filter(el => el.mine).map( el => el.name);
```

See the full code below.

```js
var dogNames = [
  {name: "Kevin",     mine: false},
  {name: "Remington", mine: true},
  {name: "Bingo",     mine: false},
  {name: "Ruger",     mine: false},
  {name: "Ruby",      mine: true},
  {name: "Gino",      mine: false},
  {name: "Chief",     mine: true},
  {name: "Watson",    mine: false},
  {name: "Link",      mine: true}
];

var myDogs = dogNames.filter(el => el.mine).map( el => el.name);
console.log(myDogs)
```

Answer (score 1):

In your logic, when you do the `push`, you need to pass `mine.name` as parameter, instead of `dogNames.name`

And in your `forEach` when you put the `mine`, you're receiving the object like `{ name: 'Kevin', mine: false }`, so, you need specify the propertie you'll check, like in your `if` statement.

```
var dogNames = [
  {name: 'Kevin',     mine: false},
  {name: 'Remington', mine: true},
  {name: 'Bingo',     mine: false},
  {name: 'Ruger',     mine: false},
  {name: 'Ruby',      mine: true},
  {name: 'Gino',      mine: false},
  {name: 'Chief',     mine: true},
  {name: 'Watson',    mine: false},
  {name: 'Link',      mine: true}
];

var myDogs = [];

dogNames.forEach(mine => (mine.mine && myDogs.push(mine.name)));
```

Answer (score 1):

With function `reduce`.

```js
var dogNames = [  {name: 'Kevin',     mine: false},  {name: 'Remington', mine: true},  {name: 'Bingo',     mine: false},  {name: 'Ruger',     mine: false},  {name: 'Ruby',      mine: true},  {name: 'Gino',      mine: false},  {name: 'Chief',     mine: true},  {name: 'Watson',    mine: false},  {name: 'Link',      mine: true}];

var myDogs = dogNames.reduce((a, d) => {
  if (d.mine) a.push(d.name);
  return a;
}, []);
console.log(myDogs);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var myDogs = dogNames.filter(x => x.mine).map(x => x.name);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var dogNames = [
  {name: 'Kevin',     mine: false},
  {name: 'Remington', mine: true},
  {name: 'Bingo',     mine: false},
  {name: 'Ruger',     mine: false},
  {name: 'Ruby',      mine: true},
  {name: 'Gino',      mine: false},
  {name: 'Chief',     mine: true},
  {name: 'Watson',    mine: false},
  {name: 'Link',      mine: true}
];

var myDogs = [];

dogNames.forEach(function(dog){
    if(dog.mine === true){
        myDogs.push(dog.name);
    }
});

console.log(myDogs);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of solving it, let's talk about 'forEach'

The argument to Array.prototype.forEach is a function.  This function is called for each item in the array.

That function takes an argument representing a single item in the array.
So if I have:

```
var results = [];
var myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
```

and I have a function

```
function addOne(n) {
    results.push(n + 1)
}
```

I can call forEach on myArray like so

```
myArray.forEach(addOne)
```

And that will make my results array look like

```
>>> [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

I think your confusion comes in because you're working with an array of objects, and you tried to iterate on a property of the object (`mine: boolean`) rather than the object itself (`{name: string, mine:boolean}`)

In your case, you could have an array like so:

```
var secondResults = []
var myObjArray = [{a: 1}, {a: 2}, {a:3}]
```

and another function

```
function addOneToObj(obj) {
   obj.a = obj.a + 1;
   secondResults.push(obj)
}
```

you could call forEach on it

```
 myObjArray.forEach(addOneToObj)
```

and secondResults will look like

```
>>> [{a: 2}, {a: 3}, {a: 4}]
```

```js
var results = [];
var myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
function addOne(n) {
  results.push(n + 1)
}

myArray.forEach(addOne)
console.log(results); //[2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

var secondResults = []
var myObjArray = [{a: 1}, {a: 2}, {a:3}]
  
function addOneToObj(obj) {
   obj.a = obj.a + 1;
   secondResults.push(obj)
}

myObjArray.forEach(addOneToObj)

console.log(secondResults); //[{a: 2}, {a: 3}, {a: 4}
```

**Some notes about why this is a bad approach**:

Array.prototype.forEach is generally used for for side effects.  Array.prototype.forEach doesn't actually return anything.  If you're expecting an end result where you've changed the items in the array in some way, you should use .map instead.

That would simplify our prior example to:

```js
    
    var myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    function addOne(n) {
      return n + 1
    }

    var results = myArray.map(addOne)
    console.log(results); //[2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

    
    var myObjArray = [{a: 1}, {a: 2}, {a:3}]
      
    function addOneToObj(obj) {
       obj.a = obj.a + 1;
       return (obj)
    }

    var secondResults = myObjArray.map(addOneToObj)

    console.log(secondResults); //[{a: 2}, {a: 3}, {a: 4}]
```